# Is there a way to use interfaces to achieve a similar result?

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection, c#-8.0

I have an application which dynamically references types within my application at launch using reflection.

Each of my types have a constant defined in them as such:

```
public class Class : IClassInterface
{
    public const string ClassConstant = "Class Constant Value";
}
```

During my application's initialization, I access that constant through reflection as such:

```
foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().DefinedTypes)
    if (typeof(IClassInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
        string constantString = type.GetField("ClassConstant")?.GetRawConstantValue()?.ToString();
    }
```

In a completely different place in my application, I need to retrieve that constant again, which would require me to use reflection again. It seems to be a little messy and I'm wondering if someone has an idea on how I could do this perhaps a bit differently.

I originally tried using a public property instead of a constant, but I found that the property is only available once the class is instanciated, so it required me to call `Activator.CreateInstance` on each type just to read the value of a string that won't change during the application's lifetime.

The property was readable during runtime thanks to the interface, but required class instanciation. The constant does not require class instanciation, but is not readable during runtime because it cannot be defined as a member of the interface. So I'm stuck in a sort of chicken and egg situation.

Comment: how about using ``appsetting`` in the configuration : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: You can make a helper class to store a such constants or use app settings

Comment: Would your "class constants" be better as attributes? `[ClassConstant("Class Constant Value")] public class Class { ... }`

Comment: `const`s are effectively `static` and you can't include `static` members in an interface either.

Comment: The information has to be stored inside the class (due to design requirements in the overall structure).

Comment: Why do you access a constant, through reflection? Why not through it's fully qualified name, `Class.ClassConstant` like you would all others? | With interfaces you could define they have to provide a get-only property for this constants. Sensible implementation would still be up to the implementer of that interface.

Comment: Can attributes be defined within an interface and accessed through reflection without instanciating the class?

Comment: Is there a reason it cannot be a read only property defined on the interface and just have the class return the constant via the property?

Comment: Could you not have your initialization code construct a `Dictionary<Type, string>` and arrange to inject that (or a readonly view of it) to the later code that needs it?

Comment: @jscarle In C# 8 you are also [allowed to use constants in interfaces](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods.md)

Comment: The constant is accessed through reflection because I do not know ahead of time which classes I will be loading.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: Yes, I can "define" a constant in the interface, but each class has its own constant.

Comment: @jscarle If each class uses their own class cosntant, how does it mater? If other code needs the cosntant too, just write a get-only property to access it.

Comment: @juharr: Because reading the property using reflection requires the class to be instanciated.

Comment: Okay, I think it is clear that this is a XY Problem. Please go a step back and tell us what the X is, instead of trying to chase the Y further. What does this constant *do*? Why does it do that? Why does other code need a constant? Why do you not know wich classes you will be using?

Comment: I think you just gave me the solution @Christopher. I can define a read-only property through the interface and return the constant defined in each class. That allows me to read the constant through reflection without instanciating the class whilst also allowing me to access the property at runtime using the interface.

Comment: @jscarle You could also do something like [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgbgpgTglgZgTwD4AEBMBGAsAKFygZgAJ0iAxAewoEFhhYAjAV2AiJCNvpmddwG9cRYSWIwAdsHJUAagEMANkzb8iAcwjAA3EQC+QkYWk06jFhAAUEqXFmLlASiIBeAHzH5Sts6K2Kn5S1cfTwcAG1KCgsAYQA6ABUACwk1BwBdfGJSaIEDYSMAYwpxAGcpayIklJciAiCcXSA)? That avoids the need to have the magic string `ClassConstant`.

Comment: Attributes would be cleaner. I'll have to look into that. Thanks.

Comment: You could also have a method `public static string GetClassConstant<T>() where T : IClassInterface` (or an extension method `public static string GetClassConstant(this IClassInterface cls)`) which encapsulates the reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Christopher, this solution will work for my usage case:

```
public class Class : IClassInterface
{
    public const string ClassConstant = "Class Constant Value";
    public string Constant { get { return ClassConstant; } }
}

public interface IClassInterface
{
    public string Constant { get; }
}
```

Comment: Now you need to implement that property everywhere. Maybe simple extension method would be better?